# How do I copy my Microsoft Outlook data without Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: linux, windows, microsoft-outlook, file-transfer, knoppix

My family member's computer stopped running Windows recently (Vista). It said something along the lines of NTLDR is missing. The family member took it to Best Buy and they said that the hard drive was bad.

I decided to pop in Knoppix to see if I could back up some data for them. I was able to access the hard drive but now I'm having issues copying the outlook.pst over (Input/output error).

My first thought was to recursively chmod 777 on the files. I still ran into issues copying the file. So if anyone could help me out with getting this file copied over, I would be thankful.

After I get the file I am hoping to reformat the drive and see if this fixes the issue. Also, I'll probably install Windows 7 instead of Vista.

Comment: If you are getting an error while trying to copy a file it means the file is corrupt and the entire file cannot be read.  This problem has nothing to do with permissions.  You can attempt to recovery the day with programs like SpinRite which might be able to relocate the files ( and actually make the disk bootable ) it might takes days, weeks, or months to do this of course.  There are also recoery programs that might help many of those I like the one by Piriform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to copy the file after booting off a Linux LiveCD, then it definitely sounds like the hard drive is bad.  The NTFS file permissions are irrelevant when you boot to Linux.  Unfortunately, if you are unable to copy the file, there isnt much you can do.

Comment: It manages to copy the other files inside the outlook folder and only approximately half of the outlook.pst file though. I'm sure the hard drive is near the end of it's lifespan as well, but if there is any way to get the outlook data, I would look to do so. (it had work related data, taxes, and house information that unfortunately wasn't backed up)

Comment: you can try the pst repair tool.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-HA010075831.aspx

Comment: I tried 'wine scanpst.exe' and nothing happened. Not really sure at this point :/